# Shorthand for properties of generic class types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a set of TypeScript interfaces and I'm trying to write a generic class to use them. They would look like this:

```
export interface GlobalHistory {
   items: ItemHistory[];
}

export interface ItemHistory {
   snapshots: ItemSnapshot;
}

export interface ItemSnapshot {
   inUse: boolean;
}
```

I want to make a generic class ensuring that all instances will only use classes implementing GlobalHistory or its inner interfaces as types for several of its properties and methods. A possible approach would be to write it like this:

```
export abstract class SomeClass<
    T extends GlobalHistory,
    U extends ItemHistory,
    V extends ItemSnapshot
>
```

However, this is exceedingly wordy and also rather uncomfortable to use when defining concrete classes, so I realize I can also do this:

```
export abstract class SomeClass<T extends GlobalHistory> {
    public someMethod(): GlobalHistory.items[0] { ... }
    // returns ItemHistory

    public someOtherMethod(): GlobalHistory.items[0].snapshots[0] { ... }
    // returns ItemSnapshot
}
```

While technically this achieves what I want, this fails to communicate clearly what the expected return values are. So what I'd like to know is whether there is a cleaner, clearer way to achieve this - not forcing the user of the generic class to specify three type parameters instead of one, but also keeping the generic class readable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd remark that there's also the possibility of dropping generics in this case and using the interface types directly to type everything in the abstract class. The issue with this approach is that any subclass of SomeClass then wouldn't know if I'm using a class which implements (for instance) GlobalHistory as well as some extra properties not defined in the interface. If I wanted to access the extra properties, I'd need to cast everything to the right type, which is more work and error-prone. Hence my insistence on generics.